# How to secure restful webservice with oauth?

Tags: rest, oauth

I know that this question has been asked thousand times before but I am still unable to comprehend the answers properly. When I googled about this topic I found most of the people suggesting to use Oauth to secure Restful webservice.

I believe oauth is only applicable when you want third party applications to allow access to secured resources without sharing credentials of the user.

In my case I want to secure restful service which can only be accessed by our own developed mobile application. I am unable to understand that only for this purpose how I can utilize oauth to secure restful resources. My requirement is that for the first time user will enter his credentials into the application. Upon successful authentication application will receive a access token which then will be used to access secured resources.

Whereas in case of ouath user first of all gets redirected to the authorization provider website from mobile application (assuming mobile application as third party app) where he enters the credentials and then through a call back url the mobile application receives access token to gain access to secured resources.

I read Web API Design guide from Apigee in which they strongly recommends to use ouath. In fact Apigee App Services are secured using oauth and they are doing the same things which I need using oauth. As following curl command shows how to get access token using username and password as per apigee API Documentation.

`curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.usergrid.com/my-org/my-app/token" -d '{"grant_type":"password","username":"john.doe","password":"testpw"}'`

My first question is that if I follow the same approach that allows third party application to get access token without any redirection and callback, will it result in violation of Oauth specification or not?

My second question is that can we use ouath for scenarios in which no third party application is involved and secured resource access is between application user and resource provider without any kind of confirmation.

Comment: Found answer on hybris tech blog. The scenario I was discussing in the thread is covered in Oauth2 resource owner password flow.
http://techblog.hybris.com/2012/06/11/oauth2-resource-owner-password-flow/

Comment: You become your own oAuth provider, and then your Mobile application can set up its own oAuth Consumer that uses that provider.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible with OAuth2. With OAuth1 it was a bit more clumsy as you had to use '2-legged auth', which didn't feel all that natural, but in OAuth2 you can use one of these grants:

- [Authorization code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)
- [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)